# Cases in nested switch case won't run

Tags: c, switch-statement

This program is to calculate the price of dishes. The user needs to input the item number and it'll calculate the total price of the dish based on the size they chose. However, the 2nd switch case (the one inside the switch (item_number)) doesn't work as expected. It works only for case 1, the other cases 2-4 doesn't work, hence the program cannot display the accurate price. I absolutely cannot do this assignment using if...else, it has to be with switch case.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int item_number, dish_quantity;
    char dish_size;
    float price, total;

    //Display the menu

    printf("\t\t\t\tMenu\t\t\t\t\n");
            printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("Item Number   Dish\t\t\t Dish Size              \n");
            printf("\t\t\t\tSmall(RM)   Medium(RM)   Large(RM)\n");
            printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("     1        Ikan Tenggiri       10.00      20.00        30.00\n");
            printf("     2        Ikan Pari            8.00      15.00        25.00\n");
            printf("     3        Ikan Jenahak         9.00      17.00        28.00\n");
            printf("     4        Daging              10.00      20.00        30.00\n");
            printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

    // Input from user

    printf("Enter item number        : ");
    scanf("%d", &item_number);
    printf("Enter dish size (S/M/L)  : ");
    scanf("%s", &dish_size);
    printf("Enter dish quantity      : ");
    scanf("%d", &dish_quantity);

    switch (item_number){
    case 1: switch (dish_size){
                case 's': case 'S': price = 10.00; break;
                case 'm': case 'M': price = 20.00; break;
                case 'l': case 'L': price = 30.00; break;}

        case 2: switch (dish_size){
                case 's': case 'S': price = 8.00; break;
                case 'm': case 'M': price = 15.00; break;
                case 'l': case 'L': price = 25.00; break;}

        case 3: switch (dish_size){
                case 's': case 'S': price = 9.00; break;
                case 'm': case 'M': price = 17.00; break;
                case 'l': case 'L': price = 28.00; break;}

        case 4: switch (dish_size){
                case 's': case 'S': price = 10.00; break;
                case 'm': case 'M': price = 20.00; break;
                case 'l': case 'L': price = 30.00; break;}

        }

    printf("Price per dish size      : RM %.2f\n", price);

    total = dish_quantity * price;

    printf("Total charge             : RM %.2f", total);

    return 0;



}
```

Comment: I think you mean it only works for case 4. Because there is no break at the end of case 1, 2 or 3 it runs into the next case

Comment: My bad, case 1 and case 4 run perfectly, the error lies only with case 2 and case 3

Comment: because when you type 2, the computer runs case 2, then case 3, then case 4, because there is no break at the end of each one.

Comment: The `break` statement will only break out of the innermost `switch`, but not the outer `switch`. Therefore, you also need `break` statements for the outer `switch` statement.

Comment: Ah yes, that fixed it for me, I added a break; after each case and it worked. Thanks

Comment: @DashvinKumar: If your program works after making that change, then you are lucky, because your program also has a buffer overflow problem. See my answer for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the break; statements in the outer case blocks.

```
switch (item_number){
    case 1: switch (dish_size){
                case 's': case 'S': price = 10.00; break;
                case 'm': case 'M': price = 20.00; break;
                case 'l': case 'L': price = 30.00; break;}
            break; // add this at the end of each case.
```

Answer (score 4):

The `break` statement will only break out of the innermost `switch`, but not the outer `switch`. Therefore, you also need `break` statements for the outer `switch` statement:

```
switch (item_number)
{
    case 1:
        switch (dish_size)
        {
            case 's': case 'S': price = 10.00; break;
            case 'm': case 'M': price = 20.00; break;
            case 'l': case 'L': price = 30.00; break;
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        switch (dish_size)
        {
            case 's': case 'S': price = 8.00; break;
            case 'm': case 'M': price = 15.00; break;
            case 'l': case 'L': price = 25.00; break;
        }
        break;

    case 3:
        switch (dish_size)
        {
            case 's': case 'S': price = 9.00; break;
            case 'm': case 'M': price = 17.00; break;
            case 'l': case 'L': price = 28.00; break;
        }
        break;

    case 4:
        switch (dish_size)
        {
            case 's': case 'S': price = 10.00; break;
            case 'm': case 'M': price = 20.00; break;
            case 'l': case 'L': price = 30.00; break;
        }
        break;
}
```

Another problem is that the line

```
scanf("%s", &dish_size);
```

will cause a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), because `&dish_size` only has room for storing a single character, including the terminating null character. Therefore, there is only sufficient room for storing an empty string.

For this reason, I suggest that you change that line to the following:

```
scanf(" %c", &dish_size);
```

That way, `scanf` will only attempt to write a single character instead of a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 2):

You need a break statement:

```
case 1: switch (dish_size){
                case 's': case 'S': price = 10.00; break;
                case 'm': case 'M': price = 20.00; break;
                case 'l': case 'L': price = 30.00; break;
        } break;                                      //here for every case
```

And it's always a good idea to include a `default` case for every `switch`.

Comment: For this particular program, there isn't a need to make a ```default``` case due to the instructions but thank you for the reminder.